# Why Decodable's init method isn't called when using JSONDecoder.decode method?

Tags: swift, codable

I'm trying to override how JSONDecoder decode a data.

I tried the following:

```
struct Response : Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: Data())
```

But the `init(from:)` does not get called.
Basically I want the `JSONDecoder` to always success when decoding empty data to empty `Response` object

Comment: It's not called because you didn't give it any JSON data to decode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty `Data` object causes the `init` method to throw the error

> The given data was not valid JSON.

before "Hello" gets printed.

---

If you want to get an empty `Response` object (assuming you don't have to call any designated initializer) catch the `dataCorrupted` decoding error

```
struct Response : Decodable {}

var response : Response?
do {
    response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: Data())
} catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) where (context.underlyingError as NSError?)?.code == 3840 { // "The given data was not valid JSON."
    response = Response()
} catch { print(error) }
```

Answer (score -1):

Whoever comes to this page looking for a solution to force use of INIT on decodable class you just need to use:

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
```

Full example:

```
class DeviceListElement: Codable {
    
    var firmwareVersion, deviceName: String
    var status: Int
    
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firmwareVersion = "fwVer"
        case deviceName
        case status
    }
    

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        firmwareVersion = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .firmwareVersion)
        deviceName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .deviceName)
        status = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .status)
        
        
        //if is optional use this: container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .blabla)
    }
    
}
```